# Fails to prompt "Python version" and "pip list" after creating virtual environment with "virtualenv"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-venv

I want to create a virtual environment to install modules only required for a particular proj and for sharing whole package.

Versions that are installed in my system
Python 3.8.3 -- envvar set to python3
PyCharm 2020.1.2 (Community Edition)
Python 2.7(due to maya pyside2) -- envvar set to python

As per python docs
https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments
Deprecated since version 3.6: pyvenv was the recommended tool for creating virtual environments for Python 3.3 and 3.4, and is deprecated in Python 3.6.

Changed in version 3.5: The use of venv is now recommended for creating virtual environments.

I require PyQt5 for my current proj
and python3.8.3 was best suited so decided to go with it
and pycharm as my IDE

**1)** so i decided to create a virtual env through it but it prompts an error.

in case if the image is not displayed error was

**2020.1.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\packaging_tool.py pyvenv**

**Error:[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified**

I don't get it why pycharm is not able to recognize the version of python3.5 and above.

**2)** so as per above docs i started searching **venv** for couple of hours and came across many pages eg: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/steps-to-set-up-a-virtual-environment-for-python-development/
and referred the page and installed through pycharm the **virtualenv** and **virtualenvwrapper-win** and began the process again but this time through terminal and worked like a charm. env was created.
**but as we know the python.exe is required in scripts folder to run anything but that was missing**

**3)** that brings me to 3rd point i enforced the python persion with **virtualenv path/venv -p python3.exe** but still no sign of python in the environment.
and if i activate the environment "activate.bat" works fine
**pip list** in terminal
prompts me
**Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"D:\All_Projs\Maya_Projs\succinct_save\venv\Scripts\python.exe"  "D:\All_Projs\Maya_Projs\succinct_save\venv\Scripts\pip.exe" list': The system cannot find the file specified**

Help appreciated
Thank You.

Comment: You don't show the command that leads to the error shown in your first point.

Comment: Have you tried with `python3 -m venv some_name`?

Comment: for first point i was directly trying through **PyCharm** , no i later `pip install virtualenv` and then `virtualenv path/venv -p python3.exe`

Comment: Error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified    with the above command python3 -m venv some_name from terminal

Comment: yes, i opted out that option and choose **virtualenv** https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide.html#introduction

Comment: my regular venv was not working because of my foolishness, as i have dual python in my machine, i had changed the name to python3.exe for 3.8, so pycharm was not able to create venv, the fix, i just renamed it to python.exe